# Handle DOM element click event in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I have a particular situation where I cannot use VueJS HTML syntax in my code but I want to use VueJS functions to handle DOM events such as click on a button:

### The HTML:

```html
<h1 id="header">Not Clicked</h1>
<!-- I can only use simple HTML here so no "@click", "v-bind:on-click" etc. -->
<button id="mybtn" type="button">click me</button>
```

Given the button above, this is how I would use jquery to handle the click event without touching the HTML:

```js
$('#mybtn').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('header').textContent = "Clicked";
})
```

How do I write the same javascript function in VueJS without altering the HTML button with VueJS syntax?

Live demo: https://playcode.io/744155

Comment: what *VueJS functions* you want? what *situation* you have?

Comment: A VueJS function that handle click on element based on its DOM id like in jquery

Comment: Did you consider to use https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org.html especially the trigger()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this. It definitely has some code smell to it but it sounds like you have a unique use case:

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs['header'].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Do stuff
  }
},
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$refs['header'].removeEventListener('click'), (e) => {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Essentially get the element and add an event listener to it, then do stuff. Don't forget to `removeEventListener` when the component is destroyed.

If the element is still `undefined` with the code above then you'll need to wrap it in a `nextTick` like this which will ensure that the elements have not only been created, but inserted into the DOM:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(function() {
    this.$refs['header'].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      // Do stuff
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: but `header` is the id, not a `ref` so it turns out to be undefined for me

Comment: @FabioMagarelli I updated the code a bit to hopefully fix that issue. If it's still `undefined` then you'll need to wrap the code inside of the mounted lifecycle hook in a `this.$nextTick(function() { })`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer and your patient. I actually solved it by finding a way where I don't have to access the DOM.